# How to securely store and share log in credentials?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am looking for industry best practice or a ready made app to store and share passwords for for network resources.

My current situation is that I have a number of people that need to access applications as a specific superuser in order to access some features of these applications. The applications are third party build and cannot be changes to grant access to the required features for anyone but the superuser account. Normal admin accounts have elevated rights but things like creating accounts have to be done via the superuser account.

For security reasons I would like to periodically change the superuser accounts' password. Because of the number of people that need to be able to log in as superuser changing the password would be problematic and a logistical nightmare.

I'm looking to purchase or create an application that would:

- Track who is looking up the password and to what resource
- Allow me to specify what passwords a user can retrieve
- The data should be stored and transmitted ultra securely
- Preferable this would be an on-line application (I have Mac and Windows clients)

Answer (score 2):

[Keypass](http://keepass.info/) is great for this kind of thing. It provides a strong encrypted database of passwords and secure information. This can be accessed share via svn/dropbox/fileshare implementations using a master password.

This is more for a master database of secure data you can set up additional databases, maybe per user, but it starts to get a little away from what it's deigned for.

Comment: I had read a little about Keypass. The problem is that I need the passwords to be in one location that my team can access (Keypass can do this) but the application should only display the credentials of systems that the user has been allowed to see.

Comment: You could create a Keypass database for each user, but as I say perhaps moving away from it's true purpose . There might be better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a C# app that checks with a web service if the user can run the app and with what permissions, it would then be sent the encrypted credentials for a 1 time run, the service would log the request.  This would all have to be done securely, so the service would use SSL and preferably certs between the systems.  You have a good bit of research here to figure this all out, and you might have to use Java if you want mac... but I dont know how well that can launch apps as other users.

Solution #2 would be to use KeePass.  You will have to be creative.